# Redirect 404 error pages to another host

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

What I would like to do is to redirect visitors hitting the 404 error page on my main website (say example.com) to another host.

For example:
A visitor hits the page https://example.com/abc which doesn't exist.  I would like to redirect him to https://another-host.example.com/abc and so on.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Did you try to do it ? If you did, show us some code and where you had problems please. But it seems to be a simple http call

Answer (score 0):

first get the error code on routes then you apply your redirect process under condition

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any framewor, it will have a default routing and 404 handler built in, all you need to do is extend that handler to do a redirect. If that is just a plain code, use apache to do your redirects: Google box responce when searching for apache 404 redirect (applies to internal paged or external domain redirects):

"ErrorDocument 404 /index.html means that when the client access a non exist URL, Apache will redirect to index.html page."

Answer (score 0):

or 
In your error_404.php page write  `header("location:https://another-host.example.com/abc");`

or
In your error_404.php page write  `redirect("location:https://another-host.example.com/abc");`

or

`$(function(){
location.href = "https://another-host.example.com/abc";
});`